# Can use Order By on view

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to order a view called `listeModePays`. Here's my view in SQL

```
SELECT
   paiementEtranger.pays.nomPays, 
   paiementEtranger.mode.pays,
   [... other columns ...]
   paiementEtranger.choixMode.hierarchie 
FROM            
   paiementEtranger.choixMode 
   INNER JOIN paiementEtranger.mode 
       ON paiementEtranger.choixMode.id = paiementEtranger.mode.mode 
   INNER JOIN paiementEtranger.pays 
       ON paiementEtranger.mode.pays = paiementEtranger.pays.id
WHERE
    (paiementEtranger.pays.supprime = 0) AND
    (paiementEtranger.mode.supprime = 0)
```

And then I'm trying to ORDER By a part of this view using this query

```
SELECT * FROM paiementEtranger.listeModePays 
WHERE pays="xxx" ORDER BY choixMode.hierarchie
```

When I add the `ORDER BY choixMode.hierarchie` in my query, I get a "multi-part identifier "choixMode.hierarchie" could not be bound" error. Anybody can help?

Comment: You're selecting only from listeModePays, so you can't order by with something from choixMode -- so remove the choixMode from there, it should work since the column should have the same name

Comment: You have choixMode.hierarchie as a column in your view, just order by hierarchie in your select (no choixMode - that table doesn't mean anything if you select from the view)

Comment: Ah ok got it! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Suggestion: make use of aliases in your SQL: `…FROM LongTableName t` and then you can use `t` rather than `LongTableName` in the rest of the query. This will (with a little naming care) make things much clearer.

Comment: @Richard - its a view.

Comment: You will order by `choixMode.hierarchie` if you do what Jamie Pollard said @MaximePouliot.

Comment: @Jamiec s/Table/View/ (makes no difference)

Comment: It's working now. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Richard - oh I thought you were saying for the purpose of selecting from the view. But you're absolutely right, for writing a long select statement

Answer (score 3):

Your question just shows a `SELECT` statement, but you describe it as a view - so assuuming the statement defined is a view, you simply do not need the table name - the view has a column called `hierachie` which is sourced from the `choixMode` table.

So, you simply want

```
SELECT * FROM paiementEtranger.listeModePays 
WHERE pays="xxx" 
ORDER BY hierarchie
```